# What is the output of print exception and why doesn't it match the string outputed

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following block of code:

```
dictionary = dict()
dictionary[0] = {}
        
try:
    print(dictionary[0]["tomato"])

except Exception as e:
    print(e)          # prints 'tomato'
    print(str(e))     # prints 'tomato'
    
    if str(e) == 'tomato':
        print("Not tomato")     # never prints, why?
```

Even though `print(e)` prints `'tomato'`, `str(e) == 'tomato'` is not `True`
Can someone please explain how can this be?

Comment: `if str(e) == "'tomato'":` - there are quotes around `'tomato'` that are part of the string.

Comment: You are getting a KeyError which is why print(e) includes the quotes around tomato since `'tomato'` is the missing key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those first two print statements print `'tomato'` *including* the single quotes, so that means the quotes are literally part of the string.

Change your if statement to this:

```
if str(e) == "'tomato'":
```

Comment: While trying to answer my question I realized that str(e)==repr('tomato') would also work